# Is there a high-level roadmap for Chrome development?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-beta

Is there anywhere that I can find a high level feature roadmap for the Chrome browser?

I’m aware of [this site](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/), which documents the major changes of each release. (But this only is for the current release, not upcoming). Example of the type of information I’m looking for:

> Some highlights of these changes are:
>
> - Improved Wi-Fi stability on some Chromebooks
> - Guest mode wallpaper has been updated to Material Design
> - Remote Assistance to Chrome OS devices available via Chrome Remote Desktop
> - Some devices have been updated to the new freon graphics stack, which will provide performance improvements down the line

I’m also aware of the [“Chromium Development Calendar and Release Info”](http://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar) which lists versions and release dates, but does not describe what’s in each upcoming release.

However, what I can’t seem to find is a place combining the two, where I can see a list of upcoming releases and the major features for each.

**Example:** Google has announced a plan to gradually deprecate support of SHA1, and [this blog post](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html) lists the implementation plan for the deprecation. This is just one change; where is the overall calendar kept? Where can I see the calendar or roadmap of what other changes will be coming?

Comment: For features affecting website developers, there is [www.chromestatus.com](https://www.chromestatus.com/features).  Other than that, I have also been unable to find a nice high level view.

Answer (score 4):

You can find it at the following link: https://chromestatus.com/roadmap

Comment: Link only answer is not so usefull.

Comment: @Toto: what other answer could you give to this question?

Comment: @MátéJuhász: I couldn't give another answer but this one will be useless when the link will be broken, that all I can say. An answer must give concrete explanation, links are just a must to have.

Comment: @Toto: the questions ASKS FOR THE LINK!!! This question is off-topic here,  but the only correct answer is this one.

Comment: Page not found :(

Comment: yeap, the linked changed after 5 years. It is now correct again :)